# Serializing Class Derived from Generic Collection yet Deserializing the Generic Collection

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a Repository Class with the following method...

```
public T Single<T>(Predicate<T> expression)
{
    using (var list = (Models.Collectable<T>)System.Xml.Serializer.Deserialize(typeof(Models.Collectable<T>), FileName))
    {
        return list.Find(expression);
    }
}
```

Where Collectable is defined..

```
[Serializable]
public class Collectable<T> : List<T>, IDisposable
{
    public Collectable() { }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

And an Item that uses it is defined..

```
[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Titles")]
public partial class Titles : Collectable<Title>
{
}
```

The problem is when I call the method, it expects "Collectable" to be the XmlRoot, but the XmlRoot is "Titles" (all of object Title).

I have several classes that are collected in .xml files like this, but it seems pointless to rewrite the basic methods for loading each up when the generic accessors do it - but how can I enforce the proper root name for each file without hard coding methods for each one? The [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot] seems to be ignored.

When called like this...

```
var titles = Repository.List<Models.Title>();
```

I get the exception

```
<Titlesxmlns=''> was not expected.
```

The XML is formatted such as. ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Titles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Title>
        <Id>442daf7d-193c-4da8-be0b-417cec9dc1c5</Id>
    </Title>
</Titles>
```

Here is the deserialization code.

```
  public static T Deserialize<T>(String xmlString)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer XmlFormatSerializer
            = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        StreamReader XmlStringReader = new StreamReader(xmlString);

        //XmlTextReader XmlFormatReader = new XmlTextReader(XmlStringReader);

        try
        {
            return (T)XmlFormatSerializer.Deserialize(XmlStringReader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            XmlStringReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show an example of the XML you want. Also, FYI, the XML Serializer ignores the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Now show the complete exception you received. Catch it, then post the output of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: "<Titles xmlns=''> was not expected." on Deserialization. (I already have the XML files. They were generated by the same serializer and have been working fine with hard-coded types)

Comment: If I change the root in ALL of my xml files to something like "ArrayOf[objectname]" it works. Or if I go through a proxy class - but that's kind of pointless and it defeats the goal of what I am going for. I essentially need it to obey the root name.

Comment: @Stacey: I meant to catch the exception (call it `ex`), then post the result of calling `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Models.Title' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Title]'.\r\n   at System.Xml.Serializer.DeserializeList[T](String xmlString) in F:\\Development\\Visual Studio 2010\\App\\Appr\\Source\\XmlSerializer.cs:line 108"

Comment: @Stacey: BTW, do you call `Repository.List<T>` or `Repository.Single<T>` to deserialize?

Comment: I've tried it with both. But both use the same code, so I can't see what the difference would be.

Comment: @Stacey: the difference is that you only showed us `Single`, and I had to infer that `List` used the same deserialization code. Also, you might try posting something closer to the real code. There is no such thing as "System.Xml.Serializer.Deserialize".

Comment: Sure, No problem. I've posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense for the root of a document to *be* a collection. It may *contain* a collection, but it cannot *be* one.

---

Your problem appears to be simpler. You cannot create a serializer using an open generic type (`Models.Collectable<T>`). Try using `typeof(Titles)` instead.

---

I'm making some assumptions about your repository classes, but would something like this work?

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    protected static TextReader FileName { get; set; }

    public static TCollection List<TCollection>()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (TCollection));
        return (TCollection) ser.Deserialize(FileName);
    }

    public static TItem Single<TItem, TCollection>(Predicate<TItem> expression) 
        where TCollection : IDisposable, IEnumerable<TItem>
    {
        using (var list = List<TCollection>())
        {
            return list.Single(item => expression(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have just called the Serializer on a Collection, and that's how it outputs the file. It's always worked before, this is just the first time I've tried to use Generics with it.

Comment: Have you always used `XmlRoot`?

Comment: Yes, I have always used that on all of my classes that are intended for serialization.

Comment: Yes, that does work. Except the goal is to avoid writing 15 repositories for all of the various types.

Comment: @Stacey: I don't understand. You already have the `Titles` type. Just use it in the `typeof` expression. If necessary, change your `Single` method to take both the collection type and the collected type.

Comment: Then I have to have the same method twice. I have over 15 of these types of collections stored in XML files. I need to have repositories for ALL of them. If I hardcode the type, then I'm just repeating myself 14 more times, and increasing the workload and margin for error in editing and maintaining.

Comment: @Stacey: your underlying problem is that it's necessary to deserialize the exact same type that you serialized. You want to serialize `Titles` but deserialize `Collectable<Title>`. You can't do that.

Comment: It worked! Oh my heavens! I see what you're doing. I think I was on the right track, but I wasn't thinking abstract enough. Thank you so much, this will help immensely. So what you're doing is passing collections that were serialized as the types, which will return the objects within it ,but you're also accepting the type itself for singular construction?

Comment: @Stacey: that's one way to think of it. I find it simpler to thing that I have to deserialize the same type I serialized. In your case, this means the `XmlSerializer` instance you create to serialize must be created with the same `Type` parameter as the one you created to deserialize. In your scenario, that means passing the type as a type parameter.

Comment: Yes! It makes sense now! I just didn't think far enough ahead. Thank you so much. Both of you. I've learned so much about serialization and generics tonight!